# React Native - Tailwind CSS autocomplete in VSCode for twrnc package

Tags: react-native, npm, tailwind-css

I am using [twrnc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twrnc) package for using Tailwind CSS in React Native Project.

The syntax for that is,

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text style={tw.style`text-green-500 font-bold`}>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
  <StatusBar style="auto" />
</View>
```

But I am not getting suggestions from VSCode for Tailwind CSS classes. Can anyone suggest or help to get suggestions for classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven’t already, install the [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss).

This extension’s autocomplete and code hinting will only work on props named `className` or `class`, which React Native’s components do not have. So I’ve found that a worthwhile workaround is to implement your own versions of the React Native components and use those instead. Your version can have a `className` prop, which enables the suggestions from VSCode for Tailwind.

For example, your implementation of Text:

```
import { Text as TextRn } from "react-native";
import tw from "twrnc";

const Text = ({ className, children, ...rest }) => {
  return <TextRn style={tw.style(className)} {...rest}>{children}</TextRn>
};

export default Text;
```

And the usage:

```
import View from "./src/Text"; // or wherever you added the Text.js file

// ...

<Text className="text-green-500 font-bold">Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
```

Comment: Are you using a Tailwind CSS extension for VS code?

Comment: @JamieGarcia Yes, I am using Tailwind CSS IntelliSense https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss

Comment: You can also use the experimental class regex setting so you don't need to use. a wrapper component: https://github.com/jaredh159/tailwind-react-native-classnames/discussions/124#discussioncomment-2089837

Answer (score 5):

First install Tailwind CSS IntelliSense extenstion. Then in the setting, add style to class attributes

Comment: Can you please show me where to add and what to add exactly?

Comment: When you open the settings of that extension, there are first a few attributes that you can add your attribute (style)

Comment: @AkshitaKaretiya Did this work for you? I tried but it did not.

Answer (score 5):

```
 - //Use TailwindCss in ReactNative:

  - Install twrnc: npm install twrnc
  - import tw from "twrnc";
  - Be sure to install the TailWind CSS Intellisense extension in VS code 
  - Go to the extension settings and
  add 'style' in Class Attributes 
  - Go to your project root folder and
  manually create a file named 'tailwind.js' or 'tailwind.config.js'
  - Start using TWCSS as in the docs: eg; <View style={tw`bg-gray-300
  flex flex-1 px-5 pt-20`}>
```

Comment: `manually create a file named 'tailwind.js' or 'tailwind.config.js'` this is what I missed

Answer (score 0):

I'll extend @Brandon's answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/71718286/7733418 ).

After installing [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss), what worked for me was to add a new attribute named "style" under the extension's settings.

[image: Tailwind CSS IntelliSense extension settings]

Comment: You know that commenting requires a privilegre you do not have yet. In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (and answer post) for something it is not meant for and which you are not yet allowed to do. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead Please delete this, if you still think it is a comment.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35537302)